# Javascript trying to implement history API

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

So, I am trying to store a `history.go(-1)` into a variable to use in a function, yet when I execute it, it gives the error

> unable to read style.

I am using CSS for the animations and to show only one block of content at a time.

```js
function openChoice(evt, choiceName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks, last;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(choiceName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";

  history.pushState(null, null, choiceName.split('/').pop());



}

// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();

var bbac = history.go(-1);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Haveltica", sans-serif;
}


/* Style the tab */

div.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

choice {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}


/* Style the buttons inside the tab */

div.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.tablinks {
  background-color: #f44336;
  border: none;
  color: G;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px 22px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 8px;
}


/* Change background color of buttons on hover */

div.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}


/* Create an active/current tablink class */

div.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}


/* Style the tab content */

.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}

.tabcontent {
  -webkit-animation: fadeEffect 1s;
  animation: fadeEffect 1s;
  /* Fading effect takes 1 second */
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeEffect {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeEffect {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openChoice(event, 'Slide1')" id="defaultOpen">Reset</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openChoice(event, bbac)">Back</button>
</div>
<!-- Enter KBA info in the next line add tabcontent to class="tabcontent" of div-->


<div id="Slide1" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Title</h3>x
  <p>
    CONTENT OF SLIDE<br /><br />
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openChoice(event, 'Slide2')">Slide2</button> <br /><br />
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openChoice(event, 'Slide3')">Slide3</button> <br /><br />
  </p>
</div>
<div id="Slide2" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Title 2</h3>
  <p>
    <h4>Having fun?</h4>
  </p>
</div>
<div id="Slide3" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Title 3</h3>
  <p>
    <i>Image</i>
    <img src="null" />
  </p>
</div>
```

Here is an example of what I have so far:

http://kbadesigner.tvgesports.com/TEST%20KBA25.html

What I am trying to accomplish is the back button to return to the previous slide selected.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual error is not "unable to read style." It is:

> null is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementById(choiceName).style')

`choiceName` is supposed to be a DOM ID, but you've actually put this into it instead:

```
 var bbac = history.go(-1);
```

...which naturally returns null when you try to call `document.getElementById` on it.

Here's a rewrite of your code which uses an array of IDs rather than the window history object.  (You tagged the question with jquery so I've used that for convenience:)

```js
var pastSlides = [];

var prevSlide = function() {
  if (pastSlides.length == 0) return;
  $('.tabcontent').hide();
  $('#'+pastSlides.pop()).show();
}

var openSlide = function(slide) {
  pastSlides.push($('.tabcontent:visible').attr("id"));
  $('.tabcontent').hide();
  $('#'+slide).show();
}

var resetSlides = function() {
  pastSlides = [];
  $('.tabcontent').hide();
  $('#Slide1').show();
}

resetSlides();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="resetSlides()" id="defaultOpen">Reset</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="prevSlide()">Back</button>
</div>

<div id="Slide1" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Title</h3>
  <p>CONTENT OF SLIDE</p>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openSlide('Slide2')">Two</button> 
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openSlide('Slide3')">Three</button>
</div>
<div id="Slide2" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Title 2</h3>
  <h4>Having fun?</h4>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openSlide('Slide1')">One</button> 
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openSlide('Slide3')">Three</button>
</div>
<div id="Slide3" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Title 3</h3>
  <p><i>Image</i></p>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openSlide('Slide1')">One</button> 
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openSlide('Slide2')">Two</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I agree but how do I pull the name of the previous slide without using the browser history, since some of these decision trees are 50-60slides long?

Comment: I've updated the answer to demonstrate one way to do that.  (The browser history does not contain the slide ID, it can't be used the way you're trying to use it.)

Comment: That does the trick, the only issue is that the "slides" are a decision tree, since slide 2 & 3 are the options for slide 1, but slides 4 & 5 are the options of slide 2 while slide 6 & 7 are the options of slide 3.

Comment: In that case you'll need to capture the "previous" slide's ID (instead of the browser history object) when the user navigates to the "next" slide.

Comment: Yup, that´s where my issue stands at, on how would I go about capturing that ID. I'm currently attempting it like this: 

<button name="name" id="name" onchange="nameofS(this)" />   
<script>
nameofS(this)

function nameofS(item) {
    var id = $(item).attr("id");
    alert(id);
}
</script>

Comment: There are lots of ways, of course, but `$('.tabcontent:visible').attr("id")`  (before exiting the previous slide) would do it.

Comment: I am attempting that but I click the back button with the prevslide() it doesn´t open any slide, how can I go about capturing the id before exiting the slide?

Comment: Okay.  Last try. I've updated the answer again.  This pushes the past IDs onto an array so the slides can appear in any arbitrary order; `prevSlide` pops the last ID off the array.

Comment: Im not sure if Im doing it wrong but it seems to not open slide 1 as a starter and it wont open any even If a button is created

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing wrong either.  It works fine in the snippet.

Comment: Thanks a lot Daniel, You really helped me out. The issue was the CSS was conflicting with the JQuery.